# why variable name "sum" cause error [Python]

Tags: python, variables

Hi I did the following code for a [Leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-digits/)

```
class Solution(object):
def addDigits(self, num):
    """
    :type num: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    while(1):
        if num in list( range(0,10) ):
            return num

        sum = sum( int(i) for i in str(num) )

        num = sum
```

It yielded an error `Line 11: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sum' referenced before assignment`. It was be fixed by changing variable `sum` to `sum1`.

`sum` is not in the [list of illegal variable names (keywords)](http://www.pythonlearn.com/html-008/cfbook003.html#note3) (section 2.3).

So why error? Is it that, when python sees `sum = sum(...)`, python starts to treat `sum` as a variable and forget it's a function?

Comment: Exactly. So do not call it `sum`.

Comment: where do you initialize `sum` ? Is it a function? If so, why do you assign it ?

Comment: @ismailsunni but `sum()` is a **Python** built-in fuction.

Comment: @itwasntme ah yes, you are right. I was questioning why did he use it as variable.

Comment: Hint: If you uniformly replace `sum` with a different name, you'll get the same error.

Comment: one thing i don't understand, you first assigning the value to sum, and then assigning the sum to num. Why don't you assign directly it to num?

Comment: why are you using a class?

Comment: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python

Comment: Thanks folks! @Ahsanul Haque I did that to make it understandable to myself...  @Padraic Cunningham Leetcode provides a frame within a class - took me a while to get used to it...  @Karoly Horvath I replaced the variable `sum` (not the function `sum`) with `sum1` and it worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can definitely call your variables "sum","file" and "reduce". And it will really work if you are doing it in the global scope. For example :

```
In [6]: sum = sum(range(1,10))
```

sum will equal 45 and everything is great. (Despite the fact you can't use function **sum** anymore.)

But when you are trying to use this inside the function : interpreter defines it's own scope for variables defined inside the function.

```
In [2]: def f():
   print type(sum)
   sum = sum(range(1,10))
f()
```

You may expect the answer will be "builtin_function_or_method" but actually you will get the same error as above.
Hope someone will provide better explanation for the details of python interpreter.

Answer (score 5):

`sum` is a built-in function. This is not a problem in itself, as you can reassign it, e.g. the following works just fine:

```
sum = 1
```

The problem is that it's also on the right hand side of the assignment in a *function*:

```
sum = sum( int(i) for i in str(num) )
      ---
```

Since you're using `sum` as a *local variable*, the name on the right hand side will also refer to this local variable (and not to the built-in function). At this point you haven't given it any value yet (it's before the assignment), yet you're trying to use it, so it's an error.

Just give your variable a different name.

Answer (score -3):

*UPDATED with consideration for comments below*

sum is a built-in function (which you use on line 11)

so you <s>cannot</s> should use it as a variable name https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

The following is a bit too much of an opinion

The error is a bit unclear in this case as the interpreter tried to use sum as a variable instead of a function.

Comment: o'really? then try `sum = 1`.

Comment: >>> sum =1
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = sum(l)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: and >>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = sum(l)
>>> b
10

Comment: so what? what are you trying to demonstrate here? what you've said - "so you cannot use it as a variable name" - is still patently false.

Comment: agree, still since most of the code python i encountered is based upon convention it would be wrong to use it. also since he said it is for an online test platform it would be wrong to use in any case

Comment: Of course, but that asks for a different wording ("shouldn't" - with explanation, instead of "cannot"). It also makes your answer incorrect, because you certainly "can" (but you "shouldn't").

Comment: should -> shouldn't