# How to calculate the sum of the output of a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, sum

I've built a for loop that goes through the values of a list, enters them as keys for two dictionaries and multiplies the 2 key values together.

When you print, it gives each multiplied value on a new line.

I'd like to add the values together to get a combined total but thus far have not been able to.

```
#The list and two dictionaries 

List1 = ['coffee', 'tea' , 'cake' , 'scones' ]  

Dictionary1 ={'coffee' :'4', 'tea' :'2' , 'cake' :'6' , 'scones' :'8' }

Dictionary2 = { 'coffee':'25' , 'tea':'18' , 'cake':'45' , 'scones':'30' }


#the for function which runs through the list

for i in range(len(List1)): 
  t = ((int(Dictionary1[List1[i]])*int(Dictionary2[List1[i]]))) 

#now if you print t the following is printed:

100
36
270
240
```

I'd like to get the sum of these values, but so far I have not been able to.

In order to do so, I've tried sum(t) which produces the error:

> ">TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

I thought that might be a concatenation error so I tried sum(int(t)) but this does not work.

I've also tried turning it into list() " x = list(t) as well as replacing the lines with commas with `.replace("\n",",")`.

All feedback welcome, I think this is probably easily solved but I just haven't been able to get there - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list comprehension that does the job

```
total = sum(int(Dictionary1[x]) * int(Dictionary2[x]) for x in List1)
```

Output:

```
646
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get you  right and thinking in the simplest way, you can assign a variable and add up it in every iteration like:

```
res = 0
for i in range(len(List1)): 
  t = ((int(Dictionary1[List1[i]])*int(Dictionary2[List1[i]])))
  res += t

print(res)
```

**Edit:** And as @patrick suggests and discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32284455/4636715), the variable name edited not to be `sum`

Comment: To clarify if needed, `res += t` means `res = res + t`. Since this is a basic question the reader might not be familiar with += notation.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory:  `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` when executing `t`. That means `t` is just a sigular int value. The [built in `sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) needs an iterable to operate on.

You need to add your int to something for each iteration:

```
List1 = ['coffee', 'tea' , 'cake' , 'scones' ]  

Dictionary1 ={'coffee' :'4', 'tea' :'2' , 'cake' :'6' , 'scones' :'8' }

Dictionary2 = { 'coffee':'25' , 'tea':'18' , 'cake':'45' , 'scones':'30' }


# accumulate your values into s
s = 0
for i in range(len(List1)): 
  t = ((int(Dictionary1[List1[i]])*int(Dictionary2[List1[i]]))) 
  s += t

print(s) # print sum
```

Outputs:

```
646
```

You can however create a generator comprehension and use the [built in `sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function as well:

```
print (sum ( int(Dictionary1[a])*int(Dictionary2[a]) for a in List1))
```